# exit code in mocha.js in Node.js

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, process, mocha.js

I am testing a function which actually prints on the console at the end. I check for that on stdin and assert accordingly. But if I do this then the process only ends if I press enter key on the keyboard or call `process.exit(0)` in `after()` of outer most `describe()`. Now if I call `process.exit(0)` then even if the test cases are failing, I still get exit status of 0, How do I exit with mocha's exit code? Or is there a better way of achieving this (I don't intend to change my code as it is a CLI tool).

My testing code:

```
describe('Testing createTestExecutionForTestCases(testExecutionData)', () => {

    const testExecutionData = {
      info: {
        summary: 'summary',
      },
      tests: [{
        testKey: 'KEY-11',
        comment: 'failed',
        status: 'FAIL',
      }],
    };
    before(() => {

      const basePath = `${JIRAConfig.host}:${JIRAConfig.port}`;
      process.env.TOKEN = 'fake_token';
      const issueSearch = nock(basePath);
      issueSearch
        .post(`${JIRAConfig.testExecutionEndpoint}`, () => true).reply(200, {
          testExecIssue: {
            id: '11410',
            key: 'KEY-1',
            self: 'http://172.16.201.132:8080/rest/api/2/issue/11410',
          },
        })
        .post(`${JIRAConfig.testExecutionEndpoint}`, () => true).reply(404, {
          error: 'ERROR',
          errorMessage: 'Summary could not be empty',
        });

    });

    after(() => {

      nock.cleanAll();

    });

    it('Should create test execution issue in JIRA', async () => {

      await createTestExecutionForTestCases(testExecutionData);

      process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');

      process.stdin.on('readable', () => {

        const chunk = process.stdin.read();
        if (chunk !== null) {

          expect(chunk).to.be.a('string');
          expect(chunk).to.equal('Test Execution created with ID KEY-1');

        }

      });

    });

    it('Should not create test execution issue if any of the mandatory is not present', async () => {

      await createTestExecutionForTestCases(testExecutionData);

      process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');

      process.stdin.on('readable', () => {

        const chunk = process.stdin.read();
        if (chunk !== null) {

          expect(chunk).to.be.a('string');
          expect(chunk).to.equal('Unable to create Test Execution');

        }

      });

    });

  });
```

Comment: i think createTestExecutionForTestCases function is creating some process which is not exiting. check if your function has any running. if any process is running mocha will not exit on its own.